# How does 'finally' block in android run

Tags: java, android

In android, for code under a finally block:

```
1548 finally {
1549                /*
1550                 * clean-up everything...
1551                 */
1552                synchronized (sGLThreadManager) {
1553                    stopEglSurfaceLocked();
1554                    stopEglContextLocked();
1555                }
1556            }
```

Does it mean it will be run by the 'FinalizerDaemon'?

And what does it mean when the trace.txt shows FinalizerDaemon is waiting on a ReferenceQueue?

```
  "FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419d0c60 self=0x50cf3650
  | sysTid=3933 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1086157112
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=32 stm=9 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x416da5d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: finally is part of try/catch block and runs whenever an exception was thrown or not. FinalizerDaemon is related to garbage collection

Answer (score 6):

Finally is executed at the end of a try catch block regardless of whether or not an exception occurs.

FinalizerDaemon is not related to this. It is related to garbage collection.

Comment: well, if that was all then it wouldn't matter if you would put it below the catch block or in a finally block. :) But there's more to it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: If there's more to something @Frank you need to point what that is out here.

Comment: :) mostly: you can use it without the catch, it will always (unless terrible things happen) run. Also on uncaught exceptions. Also, if you manually call "return X" somewhere in your code, it still runs the finally. So for cleaning up / closing objects it's perfect: if a future developer adds a return statement somewhere inside the method: no worries, the finally will still run.

Answer (score 5):

`finally` and finalizers are not related.

`finally` is a block of code after a `try`-`catch` block that will run regardless of the outcome of the `try`-`catch`. It's usually where you will find crucial cleanup code to prevent resource leakage.

Finalizers (an object's `finalize()` method) can be run by the garbage collector when the object is cleaned up. However, you're not guaranteed they'll run, nor run in any order, etc.

FinalizerDaemon is likely a thread that is running `finalize()` methods. In this case, it sounds like it's blocking on a `ReferenceQueue`, which is going to hold references to objects that are eligible to be finalized.

For what it's worth, there's no behavior here that is Android-specific; this is just Java behavior.